# regex for finding specific url including <a href..> html tag

Tags: regex, parsing, text, jenkins

Here is the Console log:

```
10:16:02 2016-08-10 10:16:01.087 [INFO] (1): DEVICE_DAILY_SKIPS_SUBSCRIBER=60
10:16:02 2016-08-10 10:16:01.087 [INFO] (1): DEVICE_DAILY_SKIPS_REGISTERED=48
10:16:02 2016-08-10 10:16:01.088 [INFO] (1): DEVICE_HOURLY_STATION_SKIPS_SUBSCRIBER=6
10:16:02 2016-08-10 10:16:01.284 [INFO] (1): Post results =true
10:16:02 2016-08-10 10:16:01.290 [INFO] (1): Calling Api......
10:16:05 2016-08-10 10:16:04.289 [INFO] (1): Run URL = <a href="https://sv5.ad.mobile.com/index.php?/runs/view/2435" target="_blank">Run = R2435</a>
10:16:05 2016-08-10 10:16:04.293 [INFO] (1): [CONFIGURATION BeforeSuite] AbstractBaseTest#setUpBeforeSuite
10:16:05 2016-08-10 10:16:04.307 [INFO] (1): SHORT_TIMEOUT: 1000
```

Above is the Jenkins build console log and I am in the process of parsing it to find the desired URL along with the enclosing `<a href..` html tag. For example in above log, I want to find this: `<a href="https://sv5.ad.mobile.com/index.php?/runs/view/2435" target="_blank">Run = R2435</a>` with the help of Regular Expressions.

Here is what I have tried:

`<a href="https://sv5.ad.mobile.com/index.php?/runs/view/.*">` but does not seem to work. Also, is there a way to have a little compact regular expression for such kind of this search? How to find such URLs in the logs with the help of regex?

Comment: You are aware of that the `?` is a special character in regular expressions? So are dots.

Comment: what about `(<a href.*</a>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you escape the `.`s and `?`s, what you had already should mostly work. You need to also allow for other attributes like `target="_blank"`:

```
<a href="https://sv5\.ad\.mobile\.com/index\.php\?/runs/view/[^"]*"[^>]*>
```

`[^"]*` means "any number of characters that aren't double quotes", and `[^>]*` similarly means "any number of characters that aren't right angle brackets."

You might want to be even more flexible by allowing attributes to appear preceding the `href` too:

```
<a [^>]*href="https://sv5\.ad\.mobile\.com/index\.php\?/runs/view/[^"]*"[^>]*>
```

As to whether it could be more compact, that depends on what you're trying to find. You only gave us one example, so it's pretty hard for us to speculate.